# Как создать пользовательскую схему котороой id может быть не уникальным?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Как в deno создать коллекцию в mongodb  у которой id может быть не уникальным, но пронидексированной?
Для приведенного кода при добавлении документов в user_history осуществляется проверка на уникальность по id, а нужно отключить эту проверку.

```
import db from "../db/db.ts";

export interface UserHistorySchema {
  _id?: { $oid?: string };
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
  doc_version: number;
  isDisabled: boolean;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

export const UserHistory = db.getDatabase.collection<UserHistorySchema>("users_history");
```

Comment: id -- сокращение от "идентификатор", который по определению означает "уникальный признак объекта, отличающий его от других". Думаю, для индекса лучше создать другое поле.

Comment: В MSSQL я бы создал две таблицы оснавная c id int identity(1,1), и историческая id int. В историческую таблицу писал бы изменения в основной. Думал что по аналогии можно сделать и в монго.